# Tomcat JRE UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, runtime

Recently, I sweep some old and unused JRE on my computer.
But after that, when I load Tomcat (with eclipse for example), I have this error :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Tomcat7\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA **64**-bit .dll on a AMD **64**-bit platform
```

I have reinstalled JRE 7  or 8 but same result...

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Which download of Tomcat (the exact file) was this, and what O.S.?

Comment: Tried : Tomcat 7  64 bit Windows zip and Tomcat 7 32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer.exe
OS : Windows 7 x64

Comment: What is the output when you type this on the command line: `java -version`? And is your version of Eclipse 64 bit?

Comment: Java HotSpot 64-Bit Server VM
Eclipse Luna 64 bit

Comment: I reinstall all from scratch and no error printed on startup but files are not correctly deploy, it's not the same in the tomcat webapp directory...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tcnative-1.dll Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048773/tcnative-1-dll-cant-load-amd-64-bit-dll-on-a-ia-32-bit-platform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all JDK, JRE, Eclipse installation from your PC.

Restart your PC and install a fresh copy of JDK(64 bit), Eclipse(64 bit), Tomcat(64 bit).

Use Clean Master or CCleaner to clear any residual files/registry.

This is occurring due to the either JRE/JDK is pointing to 64 bit or you are using Tomcat 64 bit server.

This has happened with me and I had to uninstall and reinstall everything to make all work together.

One thumb rule is everything should be 64 or 32 bit which I used to follow to avoid these kind of problems. Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing temp and work directory inside tomcat folder and restart tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an environment variable still pointing to the old JRE location. Check the value of the JRE_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variables.

Comment: Also make sure that CATALINA_HOME is pointing to the correct Tomcat path.

Comment: top level of the tomcat directory (C:/Tomcat7)

Comment: the webapp starts fine but i still got this error and it takes workspace files instead of tomcat files.
i.e : I change xml file directly in my tomcat folder but it's not repercuted on the webapp...