# Tomcat7tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have the same issues happening  on this  post below [tcnative-1.dll Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048773/tcnative-1-dll-cant-load-amd-64-bit-dll-on-a-ia-32-bit-platform/33159944#33159944) except  this is the  reverse
while running Tomcat-7.0.47 below are my details and logs.I have tried to follow  all  posted above with no luck...please help me!

As well I have the 64 bit JRE downloaded, and double-checked my java version

> C:\Users\franklu>java -version java version "1.7.0_55" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)

Double checked my system variables

`JAVA_HOME` points to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55`
`JRE_HOME` points to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`

I have double checked the java installed under Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features

i have double checked Java 7 update 55(64-bit) java SE Development Kit 7 Update 55(64-bit)

I have double checked properties--->java compiler and its pointing to JavaSE-1.7

Below is my logs....this is happening when trying to start Tomcat-7.0.47.Please help....i have tried to google for almost 3hrs, my head is about to explode or point me to any material...i am ready to go extra mile whatever it takes...

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Application\Tomcat-7.0.47\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source) at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source) at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.(Library.java:42) at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.initialize(Library.java:174) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init(AprLifecycleListener.java:164) at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.isAprAvailable(AprLifecycleListener.java:81) at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.setProtocol(Connector.java:541) at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.(Connector.java:71) at org.apache.catalina.startup.ConnectorCreateRule.begin(ConnectorCreateRule.java:62) at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1282) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1543) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:554) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:595) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:262) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:430) Oct 15, 2015 5:13:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init

Comment: You are trying to load a 32 bit library into a 64 bit sytem. This cannot work!

Comment: Thank   you..i have fixed  now,what  i did was i downloaded a fresh Tomcat 7.Still i am not sure why 32 bit library seat on Tomcat 7 64 bit....??But oncei re installed a new Tomcat 7 my starter was clean

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. Problem was that I had it using 64-bit java. Changing JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME to point to 32-bit java fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue in my machine, Your TOMCAT IS 64 BIT WHEREAS IT IS USING JAVA WHICH IS 32 BIT. once you get this you need to check the below:

1. Get your Tomcat and check if it is 32 bit or 64 bit (here it is 64 bit)
2. Check what java_home used by tomcat
3. Once you get the correct jdk then check java is 32 bit or 64 bit.

open cmd and hit below command:

```
java -d64 -version
```

if this tell you proper version of java then installed java is 64 else it is 32. Please get the java which is 64 version and point the same as JAVA_HOME either in environment variable or in catalina.bat file.

Hope this will correct your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue ,
I downloaded a 32 bit tomcat and added it to my Intellij and  now it works fine.